# What should I do after git mergetool?

Tags: git

I installed meld, ran `git mergetool`, merged left and right files into the center file, saved, and closed the window. I remember other times mergetool asked if merge was successful, but this time it didn't (I would have answered 'yes'). I opened my file and it was like I wanted it to be, but there was an unwanted file 'myfile.orig', so I run `git clean -fd` and it was removed. Then I did `git add -A` and `git commit -m 'merged feature-a'`. It feels like this process could have been shorter or cleaner.

- Is this the correct way to merge when there are conflicts?
- Are there other ways?

Comment: Regarding `commit -m 'merged feature-a'`, git will generate a merge commit message that gives more detail.  It's generally best to take that message and add any extra information rather than write your own from scratch.  Developers who use git will automatically recognize git's merge commits but may not recognize your custom merge messages immediately.

Comment: @AndrewMyers But I did `git log` and there wasn't any commit. I see those automated commits when the merge does not have any conflicts. Also, after my own custom commit, `git log` showed 'Merge: abc123' before the 'Author: bla' part.

Comment: If you do `git commit` without the `-m` you'll be taken into `$EDITOR` which is initialized with a merge message.  Git will always show the commit as a merge but the default merge message has a structure that other developers will instinctively recognize.

Answer (score 0):

1 : after calling an external mergetool, git just checks if the target file has been updated (e.g : if it's modification date is more recent than the backuped file date). If it is, it considers the merge was "successful", otherwise, it asks the question, to see if your intention was to keep the original file, or if you just didn't fix the merge.

So : simply hitting `ctrl+S` in `meld` is enough to skip the question, and you should know this : *always* re-read what you are about to commit after a conflict.

2 : `*.orig` files are generated by git on each solved merge conflict, it is generally advised to add these to your `.gitignore`, and to not really care.
I added a shortcut to `find . -name '*.orig' | xargs rm` in my path, which I occasionally run when I see too many *.orig files in my IDE.

3 : after a "successful" merge, git should have `git add`ed the resulting file automatically, so you could have skipped the `git add -A` step.

---

To sum it up :

- all your steps were correct,
- if you ignore `'*.orig'` files, and check that the expected files are staged, you should be able to directly call `git commit` after a successful conflict resolution.